# How to find lines of a file where 2 firsts words are differents from previous and next line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

Consider the following file:

```
word1 word2 word3
word1 word2 word3
word6 word7 word8
word6 word7 word9
word9 word10 word4
word1 word2 word5
word1 word2 word5
```

I search for a shell command line to output lines where 2 first words are different from previous and next line.

Expected output:

```
word9 word10 word4
```

Any idea?

Comment: will there always be exactly 3 space-delmited words?

Comment: why is `word6 word7 word8` excluded? this is different from first two rows and next two rows, right?

Comment: What if the 1st line is different from the 2nd - should that 1st line be printed? Ditto for the last line compared to the 2nd-last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### case 1: each line has same number of words (fields)

- `uniq` can skip initial fields but not trailing fields
- `rev` reverses the characters on a line

Since each line has the same number of fields (1 trailing), we can do:

```
<file rev | uniq -u -f1 | rev
```

### case 2: arbitrary number of words on each line

We can write an `awk` script that keeps track of the current and the previous two lines and prints the previous one when appropriate:

```
awk <file '
{
    # does current line match previous line?
    diff = !( $1==p1 && $2==p2 )

    # print stashed line if not duplicate
    if (diff && pdiff) print p0

    # stash current line data
    pdiff=diff; p0=$0; p1=$1; p2=$2
}
END {
    # print the final line if appropriate
    if (pdiff) print p0
}
'
```

Comment: Clear & nice solution Jhnc. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is some redundancy here but works

```
$ awk             '{k=$1 FS $2} 
     k!=p && p!=pp {print p0} 
                   {p0=$0; pp=p; p=k} 
               END {if(p!=pp) print}' file


word9 word10 word4
```

Comment: interesting that we wrote almost the same program :-) but I think yours does twice as many string comparisons?

Comment: yes, didn't have time to optimize, it can skip one comparison for sure, I think it can even further simplified.  But my excuse is: it's Friday!